# Problems with Facebook Open Graph

Tags: php, facebook

i have a problem with my Facebook API, i have created a custom OpenGraph and when i use the defualt settings i got a error

my code look like this.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'app-id',
  'secret' => 'secret-key',
  'cookie' => true
));


$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,read_friendlists,publish_actions,user_actions:{namespace}',
  'scope' => 'email,user_birthday,read_friendlists,publish_actions,user_actions:{namespace}'
  )
);


$response = $facebook->api(
  'me/objects/{namespace}:food',
  'POST',
  array(
    'app_id' => 660038414043289,
    'type' => "{namespace}:food",
    'url' => "http://samples.ogp.me/660043024042828",
    'title' => "Sample Food",
    'image' => "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png",
    'description' => ""
  )
);
```

But code still has bugs, i got this code from xdebug in PHP

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Cannot specify type in both the path and query parameter. thrown in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/test/reparer.nu/facebook/sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1340
```

i hope somebody out there can help me in fixing this problem.

Comment: can you take out 'type' => "{namespace}:food", from the array and try ?

Comment: Yes, now i got this error: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) The parameter object is required thrown in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/test/reparer.nu/facebook/sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1340

Comment: The code above you pasted as it is.. You need to edit the settings.. {namespace} should be replaced with your app namespace. And in the url 'url' => "http://samples.ogp.me/660043024042828" you need to add opengraph tags too..

Comment: Yes i know i need to replace my {namespace} width my own :) what are you mean width "url" to add opengraph tag?